# AngularJs: How to set same cookie on different domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, cookies

I have 2 **domains**:

1. www.site1.com
2. www.site2.com

> **Important Notes:**
>   *not sub domain!*
>   *`Allow-Origin` are enable on both domains.*
>   *have full Access to both of domains.*

**Question:**

How to set a cookie on **site1** & get that cookie on **site2** ?

**I want to use it on AngularJs, no matter if using jQuery in your examples.**

Comment: @SharnWhite, no It's ASP.NET, in that example i think we should put some file from site2 to site1 for doing proccess on cookies.

Comment: Possible related question [Cross-Domain Cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3342140/4519059) ;).

Comment: Yep, i image you can do something similar to 'Cross-domain-cookies - a maybe new idea', but via an asp script.

Comment: You should call Tom Cruise..Cause you got a mission impossible

Answer (score 2):

There is a technique that multi-site companies like google employ to keep their users logged in for all their sites per single authentication.

This question is about how **A** can read a cookie of **B**. But my answer only tells you how **A** can set a cookie in **B**. Although this technique can be employed in a useful way for OPs favor, negative points are welcome. I will still spread the awareness.

Create a php file (lets say setcookie.php) in site B. This can set a cookie for site B.

```
setcookie("MyCookie", "subinsb.com", time()+3600);
```

Now if you can call this php file from any site, it will set the cookie for site B. A famous way to call this script is via a hidden `img` tag. So, the site A can have this image tag - which will set a cookie for site B.

```
<img src="http://www.siteB.com/setcookie.php" style="display:none;" />
```

When this image is loaded, you know the cookie for site B is set.

Interestingly, you can send data too to the cookie of site B through the URL. Your `setcookie.php` can read data via `$_GET` and include them in the cookie.

[Here](http://subinsb.com/set-same-cookie-on-different-domains) is the article.

Comment: Hi, no need to negative points! :) , thank you ; but i already use ASP.NET.

Comment: I'm sure you can do in asp.net the same thing the php does. It's http protocol after all.